# fastapi_jwt_auth refresh access token by passing refresh token rather than in the auth header

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, jwt, fastapi, psql

I have the following code to refresh the access token from passing the refresh token using **fastapi_jwt_auth** library

```
@router.post('/accessTokenRefresh')
def refresh(authorize: AuthJWT = Depends()):
    try:
        authorize.jwt_refresh_token_required()

        current_user = authorize.get_jwt_subject()
        new_access_token = authorize.create_access_token(subject=current_user)
        return {"access_token": new_access_token}
    except JWTDecodeError as e:
        rex = ErrorResponse(error=1000, message="Invalid Refresh Token")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail=rex.dict())
    except Exception as e:
        handleException(e)
```

Although this works is there any way that i can modify the code so that i can pass the request token in the request body rather than in the header

```
POST /refresh-token
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "refresh_token": "<refresh_token>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JWT fastapi_jwt_auth token can only be used in 2 variants.

> **authjwt_token_location**  Where to look for a JWT when processing a
> request. The options are headers or cookies. You can pass in a
> sequence to set more than one location ('headers','cookies'). Defaults
> to {'headers'} if you pass headers and cookies, headers are
> precedence.

[Docs.](https://indominusbyte.github.io/fastapi-jwt-auth/configuration/general/)

---

For greater mobility, I recommend using the FastApi [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/).

---